# Is this Promise cancellation implementation for reducing an async iterable on the right track?

Tags: javascript, promise, reduce, cancellation, async-iterator

I'd like to enable Promise cancellation for one of the methods of my library, `reduce`. I'm only interested in cancelling the Promise for an async iterable, since these have a high likelihood to hang indefinitely.

```js
const reduceAsyncIterable = async (fn, possiblyX0, state, x) => {
  const iter = x[Symbol.asyncIterator]()
  const y0 = isUndefined(possiblyX0) ? (await iter.next()).value : possiblyX0
  if (isUndefined(y0)) {
    throw new TypeError('reduce(...)(x); x cannot be empty')
  }
  let y = await fn(y0, (await iter.next()).value)
  for await (const xi of iter) {
    if (state.cancelled) return // stops async iterating if `cancel` called
    y = await fn(y, xi)
  }
  return y
}

const reduce = (fn, x0) => {
  if (!isFunction(fn)) {
    throw new TypeError('reduce(x, y); x is not a function')
  }
  return x => {
    if (isIterable(x)) return reduceIterable(fn, x0, x)
    if (isAsyncIterable(x)) {
      const state = { cancelled: false, resolve: () => {} }
      const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        state.resolve = resolve
        reduceAsyncIterable(fn, x0, state, x).then(
          y => state.cancelled || resolve(y)
        ).catch(reject)
      })
      p.cancel = () => { state.cancelled = true; state.resolve() } // shortcircuit the Promise `p` on `cancel` call
      return p
    }
    if (is(Object)(x)) return reduceObject(fn, x0, x)
    throw new TypeError('reduce(...)(x); x invalid')
  }
}
```

The above code seems to work, but I can't help but feel like there are memory leaks here. In particular, at `await iter.next()` and `for await (const xi of iter)`. If these await statements take forever (which they likely could for an async iterator), `reduceAsyncIterable` could possibly never return. This is fine from the user's perspective because of the shortcircuit happening in `reduce`, as the Promise the user sees is resolved. But from the computer's perspective, would cancelling the Promise of this operation cause a memory leak?

I'd like to be able to use the `cancel` function on a returned promise like so:

```js
const myOngoingTaskPromise = reduce(someReducer, null)(myInfiniteAsyncIterable)

myOngoingTaskPromise.cancel() // resolves myOngoingTaskPromise with undefined

myOngoingTaskPromise // Promise { undefined }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way, `Promise.race` is like a secret weapon or something

```js
    if (isAsyncIterable(x)) {
      const state = { cancel: () => {} }
      const cancelToken = new Promise((_, reject) => { state.cancel = reject })
      const p = Promise.race([
        reduceAsyncIterable(fn, x0, x),
        cancelToken,
      ])
      p.cancel = () => { state.cancel(new Error('cancelled')) }
      return p
    }
```

No memory leaks

[image: reduce-async-iterable-promise-cancellation]

Comment: That's nice to know, btw which tool did you use for reporting memory leaks?